# What is needed for my car radio to work correctly?

Tags: troubleshooting, audio, kia, optima

My 2019 kia optima fe had a system put in but then when connected to battery it said, battery being discharged due to external device, my battery got discharged all the way one day.
What is needed to get the issue fixed, some guy told me it needs maybe something for ignition to make sure radio turns off?? Helllpp

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!